# Android Studio Kotlin type mismatch for platform types

Tags: android, kotlin

In all of my kotlin projects, I have found new warnings involving what use to be platform types. For example

```
val s: String = sharedPrefs.getString("key", "defaultValue")
```

produces a warning

`Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected`

It compiles fine though so it seems to be unrelated to kotlins enforcing nullable type. But this warning seems to have popped up in the recent weeks which may be related to a change in android studio or the kotlin plugin.

In this specific case, why doesn't the inferred type match what I provided in the 2nd argument (a `String` not a `String?`)

Comment: Are you sure it is not the `val s: String` that it claims should be `String?`? Not sure why.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce well without it `s` becomes a `String?`. Even though it's guaranteed to be non null since I provided a non null `String` for the default value. This seems to be the case in a lot of the android platform types now. I'm left wondering why they did this. Retrieving `Bundle` arguments is another one. Not only do you have to check if the key exists (because you get an internal NPE if it doesn't), but also if the data it references is null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code of [`SharedPreferences`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/content/SharedPreferences.java#263), it's defined as

```
@Nullable
String getString(String key, @Nullable String defValue);
```

Having a look at it within *Android Studio*, the code implies

```
@Contract(value="_,!null->!null")
```

But this is not defined within the source itself and not considered by *Android Studio*. When you have a closer look at the warning itself, you'll find it's the *Kotlin* **NULLABILITY_MISMATCH_BASED_ON_JAVA_ANNOTATIONS** *JVM* errors diagnostic.

Anyhow the `@Nullable` annotation is just a suggestion, and the explicit declaration takes precedence.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Is there a way to disable a kotlin specific JVM warning?

Comment: _Android Studio_ gives you some options to suppress it. I'm sadly not aware of other options.

Comment: So Any idea, how to remove this warning ?